# Übersetzung von "Guess what!"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

> **Guess what!** I met your sister yesterday!

Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen? Würde die direkte Übersetzung

> **Rate mal!** Ich habe gestern auf deine Schwester getroffen!

funktionieren? Was wären andere Möglichkeiten?

Comment: Was gefällt dir an [diesen Vorschlägen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=guess+what) nicht? Und wieso fügst du die Präposition "auf" hinzu?

Comment: @Em1 Nicht, dass mir die Vorschläge nicht gefallen, aber es ist mir schwer festzustellen, ob sie in meinem Kontext passen. Schließlich kommen die Vorschläge ohne Beispiele.

Comment: @Em1 Und ich habe die Präposition "auf" hinzugefügt, weil ich ausdrücken möchte, dass das Treffen gleichsam ein Zufall ist.

Comment: Mit "auf" dann aber als "ich *bin* gestern auf deine Schwester getroffen" - aber das klingt nicht mehr so schön flapsig wie das Original.

Comment: @boaten Hier ist der Kontext mal nicht ganz so wichtig. Die ersten drei Übersetzungen von dict.cc treffen es.. Der letzte hat ein formelles "Sie", daher die Wahl, wenn du nicht per du bist. "auf" ist in deinem Satz falsch. Ich schlage vor, es wegfallen zu lassen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Meiner Meinung nach gibt es kein gutes Äquivalent, das auch nur annähernd so oft genutzt würde wie das englische Original. Wie Abrixas2 vorschlägt, könnte man

> Stell dir vor... ich habe heute...

sagen. Eine andere Möglichkeit, besonders beliebt bei Kindern, wäre ein gedehntes

> Weißt du waaahas... ich habe heute...

Das hat allerdings einen komplett anderen Flow als das Original. 
Eine dritte Möglichkeit ist, tatsächlich ein Frage/Aufforderung daraus zu machen.

> "Rate mal wen ich heute getroffen habe!"
>   "Weiß nich'"
>   "Deine Schwester!"

Das ist meiner Ansicht nach das gängigste. Es wird im Alltag sehr oft benutzt und bringt eine schöne Gesprächsdynamik.

Comment: +1 for "Weißt du was" because it even has a comical answer, much like the english version. `Guess what? Chicken butt!` -> `Weißt du was? Der Fuchs ist kein Haas!`

Answer (score 8):

Eine geeignete Übersetzung von "Guess what!" in diesem Kontext wäre "Stell Dir vor!".

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde nicht versuchen, die Übersetzung Struktur-äquivalent anzugehen. Mich reizt hier eher der Versuch, die beiden Sätze zu restrukturieren:

> Du glaubst nicht, wen ich heute getroffen habe! Deine Schwester!

bzw. wem die gehobenere Sprache mehr zusagt:

> Du ahnst nicht, wen ich heute getroffen habe! Deine Schwester!

Answer (score 0):

`Guess what` ist ja so etwas wie ein Ausdruck der Verwunderung *für einen anderen*.

Ich würde `Denk nur!` nutzen. Ich glaube, Comics (Micky Maus) nutzen das auch so. Zumindest fiel mir das später auf, als ich Comics im Original las. Zumindest in den 1990ern wurden diese konsequent (von der berühmten [Erika Fuchs](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erika_Fuchs)) übersetzt, wobei manchmal neue grammatikalische Formen geschaffen worden sind.

Comment: Aus welcher Region kommst du, wenn ich fragen darf. Ich finde "Denk nur" extrem unidiomatisch und nicht passend. Kenne auch keinen, der das sagt. Bin aus Berlin.

Comment: Ich nutze es privat nicht, aber wie gesagt, ich habe es in Comics gelesen. Und auch in Büchern. Insgesamt aber vermutlich eine ältere und vielleicht formalere Variante.

Comment: Ich habe das Christkind gesehen!