# Difference between "vermuten" and "erraten"

Tags: meaning, verb, verb-choice

What is the difference between *vermuten* and *erraten*?

They both mean somehow guessing.
I came to think that *erraten* is actually closer to the meaning "guessing", while *vermuten* is in reality something a bit stronger than just guessing, maybe like knowing but just partially.
Is what I think correct? Is this the way to differentiate them?

Comment: I edited out the part about "Guess what" as it is a second question and has already been answered here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18602/Übersetzung-von-guess-what

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Vermuten** means **to suppose, surmise, suspect**... basically any verb that expresses the idea of thinking something without knowing it for a fact but knowing that one doesn't know it for fact.

**Erraten** is **to guess** in sense of guessing correctly.

Comment: *erraten* can be modified to mean *still guessing* >> *versuchen zu erraten*; Generally *erraten* aims for certainity while *vermuten* just gets the right direction.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper... that doesn't change the meaning of "erraten" one bit. It means "try to guess correctly". If "erraten" were changed then it would mean "to attempt making a guess". "Erraten" doesn't aim for certainty, it IS certainty. "Vermuten" on the other hand can be quite the wrong direction too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *erraten* something, you are already right. If you are still guessing, the word is *raten*.

For example:

> Guess how old I am?
>   Rate, wie alt ich bin?

If the answer is right, this phrase could follow:

> You guessed right!
>   Du hast es erraten!

*Vermuten* means to suppose something.
E.g., the doctor can say:

> Ich vermute, es handelt sich um einen Virus.